# Change color inside the borders of a checkbox

Tags: android, android-checkbox

Is there a way to change the color inside the borders of an unchecked checkbox without resorting to a custom selector. Every answer I found is either about changing the border color, or the checked state.

Here is a small example of what I want to achieve

**Unchecked checkbox default**

[image: Default]

**Unchecked checkbox with blue color**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can set android theme of the checkbox to get the color you want in your `styles.xml` add:

```
<style name="checkBoxStyle" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">checked_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">unchecked_color</item>
</style>
```

Then in your layout file :

```
<CheckBox
     android:theme="@style/checkBoxStyle"
     android:id="@+id/chooseItemCheckBox"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

This will change the checkbox color also with the border.

Comment: OP asks about unchecked color, whereas your solution is for checked state.

Comment: Using the theme, color also will be changed for uncheck state.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed textColorSecondary is the [color of the border](https://i.imgur.com/ldxJUUC.jpg), and not what's inside

Comment: @FaysalAhmed, that's not a correct assumption, sir.

Comment: @samwinston Then you need to follow this tutorial. https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-a-custom-checkbox-in-your-android-app/

Comment: @FaysalAhmed thank you, but I was looking for a way that doens't require me to use a custom selector, since all I want to do is just change one color

Comment: @samwinston did you find a solution?